# Well ordered subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, well-orders

At the entrance exam of a french school, the following problem was given :

> Characterize well-ordered subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

The only property I found was that such a subset must be at most countable, I do not know if this was what they expected or not, and I wondered if anyone had any other non-trivial characterization of such subsets ?

I noticed that a well-ordered subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ must follow the following condition :

$$ (1)\quad\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \exists \varepsilon > 0, ]x, x+\varepsilon[\cap A = \emptyset$$

Which can easily be found by noticing that you can't find a strictly decreasing sequence of elements of $A$.
From that property, we can deduce the countability of $A$ by taking $x\in A$ in (1) and picking a rationnal $r$ in $]x, x+\varepsilon_x[$.

It is also possible to associate to each $x\in A$ (except possibly $\max A$ if it exists) an element $S(x)\in A$ such that $S(x) > x$ and for all $y\in A$, $y >x\implies y\ge S(x)$.

As a last note, this exercice is meant for second year undergraduate students, but I am interested in all information about that problem !

Comment: Conversely, any countable well-ordered set is order-isomorphic to some subset of $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb Q$, for that matter).

Comment: A subset of $\Bbb R$ that is well-ordered in the inherited order is order-isomorphic to a countable ordinal number, and all countable orders order-embed into $\Bbb Q$ and hence $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition (1), together with

> $(2)\quad A$ has a least element

indeed characterizes well-ordered subsets.

You already proved one direction.

For the other direction, assume (1) and (2), and let $H\subseteq A$ be arbitrary nonempty, and set $x:=\inf H$.
By condition (2), $x$ is finite ($x\ge\min A$), and condition (1) together with the definition of infimum imply $x\in H$.

Comment: I didn't think of using that as a characterization of well-ordered subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, thank you !